# how do i fix an error of the The element video with the attribute controls must not appear as a descendant of the a element

Tags: html, video

help me make sense of this error, how should i format the code?
error: **The element video with the attribute controls must not appear as a descendant of the a element.**

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikings" target="_blank">
       <video width="512" height="288" controls>
           <source src="Videos/Vikings_Short.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       </video>
</a>
```

i've tried mixing around the code format can't seemed to find a way to fix it. i'm expecting if i click on a video, it'll direct me to a link as mentioned.

Comment: Did the posted answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without the video inside the a tag.
You can use display: grid on the parent, and then put descendants onto the same row and column.

```
<style>
    div {
        display: grid;
    }
    a, video {
        width: 512px;
        height: 288px;
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
    }
    a {
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div>
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikings" target="_blank"></a>
    <video width="512" height="288" controls>
        <source src="Videos/Vikings_Short.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```